# Performance of zeros function in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I just noticed that the `zeros` function of `numpy` has a strange behavior :

```
%timeit np.zeros((1000, 1000))
1.06 ms ± 29.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.zeros((5000, 5000))
4 µs ± 66 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

On the other hand, `ones` seems to have a normal behavior.
Is anybody know why initializing a small numpy array with the `zeros` function  takes more time than for a large array ?

(Python 3.5, numpy 1.11)

Comment: So the second matrix is 25 times larger, but only takes 4 times longer to create? That is surprising.

Comment: @JamesKPolk read it again, the second, larger array takes 4 microseconds, the first, smaller array takes 1 millisecond! I'm getting similar, though less extreme results.

Comment: I think this is probably `calloc` hitting a threshold where it requests zeroed memory from the OS and doesn't need to actually initialize it.

Comment: When the size S of a 1D array changes from 4,150,000 to 4,200,000, the time to zero it with `np.zeros(S)` changes from 5.5 ms per loop to 9.6 µs per loop. However, the number of loops in `%timeit` simultaneously changes from 100 to 100,000. My guess is that for an array of certain size and above, the difference between the slowest and fastest runs becomes large enough to trigger 1000 times more loops, which drastically improves the measurement accuracy and reduces the reported running time. Not because it is shorter, but because it is measured more accurately.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Oops, you're right. Even more surprising!

Comment: @DYZ I'm using the `timeit.timeit` function, controlling the number at `1000`, and I'm getting `0.343710215005558` for (1000,1000) and `0.0028691469924524426` for (5000,5000)

Comment: The exact threshold for me is 4193790:  `np.zeros(4193789)` is slow, `np.zeros(4193790)` is fast. I'd be interested to know exactly why 4193790 * 8 bytes (since we're allocating an array of the float64 type) is special.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This looks like `calloc` hitting a threshold where it makes an OS request for zeroed memory and doesn't need to initialize it manually. Looking through the source code, `numpy.zeros` eventually [delegates to `calloc`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/590facafcbd454fc02f96aa52c1c3412d6cccd14/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c#L212) to acquire a zeroed memory block, and if you compare to `numpy.empty`, which doesn't perform initialization:

```
In [15]: %timeit np.zeros((5000, 5000))
The slowest run took 12.65 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that a
n intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 10 µs per loop

In [16]: %timeit np.empty((5000, 5000))
The slowest run took 5.05 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an
 intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.3 µs per loop
```

you can see that `np.zeros` has no initialization overhead for the 5000x5000 array.

In fact, the OS isn't even "really" allocating that memory until you try to access it. A request for terabytes of array succeeds on a machine without terabytes to spare:

```
In [23]: x = np.zeros(2**40)  # No MemoryError!
```

Comment: In NumPy 1.21.1, the last command results in `numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 8.00 TiB for an array with shape (1099511627776,) and data type float64`.

Comment: @A.Donda: That's probably OS-dependent. (I'm surprised NumPy has its own MemoryError class, though.)